# Can't define variable in JavaScript object literal

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Why does this code work...

```
var message = {
    texts: {
        text1: 'Hello',
        text2: 'World'
    },
    greet: function() {
        console.log(this.texts.text1 + ' ' + this.texts.text2 + '!');
    }
}
message.greet();
```

...but this doesn't?

```
var message = {
    texts: {
        text1: 'Hello',
        text2: 'World'
    },
    both: this.texts.text1 + ' ' + this.texts.text2 + '!',
    greet: function() {
        console.log(this.both);
    }
}
message.greet();
```

It gives me "both is not defined" error. What am I missing here? Something's wrong with`this.both`? I'm total newbie when it comes to object literal

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'text1' of undefined`

Comment: Is it just me or should both examples not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in second case `this` is still not exist when you define `both`. if you will turn `both` to method, like in this example : http://jsfiddle.net/YyWMQ/ , it will work.

```
both: function(){ return this.texts.text1 + ' ' + this.texts.text2 + '!'}
```

Imho , good question , +1

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = {
    texts: {
        text1: 'Hello',
        text2: 'World'
    },
    // here this refers to the scope where message is defined 
    both: this.texts.text1 + ' ' + this.texts.text2 + '!', 
    greet: function() {
        console.log(this.both);
    }
}
message.greet();
```

To understand it you can try as given below

```
this.texts =  {
            text1: 'Alternate Hello',
            text2: 'World'
        };

var message = {
        texts: {
            text1: 'Hello',
            text2: 'World'
        },
        // here this refers to the scope where message is defined 
        both: this.texts.text1 + ' ' + this.texts.text2 + '!', 
        greet: function() {
            console.log(this.both);
        }
    }
message.greet();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your misunderstanding is at the following line:

```
both: this.texts.text1 + ' ' + this.texts.text2 + '!',
```

You could use as function and return a value like:

```
both: function(){ return this.texts.text1 + ' ' + this.texts.text2 + '!'; } ,
```

And finally

```
 greet: function() {
        console.log(this.both());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling greet, `this' will be the parent obj, message. This is not the case when you're actually constructing the message object. You could write something similar like:

```
var Message = function () {
    this.texts = {
        text1: 'Hello',
        text2: 'Word'
    }
    this.both = this.texts.text1 + ' ' + this.texts.text2 + '!';
}

Message.prototype.greet = function () {
    console.log(this.both);
}

message = new Message();
message.greet();
```